# Kubernetes Keycloak Gatekeeper Bad Gateway

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak

I'm trying to setup ProxyInjector to automatically inject keycloak-gateway into any container that has annotations like the following I have for a service I'm deploying on kubernetes:

```
"annotations": {
  "authproxy.stakater.com/client-id": "bitwarden",
  "authproxy.stakater.com/client-secret": "<secret>",
  "authproxy.stakater.com/discovery-url": "https://keycloak.example.com/auth/realms/realmname",
  "authproxy.stakater.com/enabled": "true",
  "authproxy.stakater.com/listen": "127.0.0.1:3000",
  "authproxy.stakater.com/redirection-url": "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
  "authproxy.stakater.com/source-service-name": "bitwarden",
  "authproxy.stakater.com/target-port": "3000",
  "authproxy.stakater.com/upstream-url": "http://127.0.0.1:80",
}
```

This is for a bitwardenrs deployment in Kubernetes.  The service is as follows:

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: bitwarden
spec:
  selector:
    app: bitwarden
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: bitwarden-http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    - protocol: TCP
      name: bitwarden-https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
  type: NodePort
```

I can access the service normally through ingress.  But when I add the annotations to authenticate in front of it, I get a 502 bad gateway error.

Checking the bitwarden pod logs, I can see the proxy container successfully starts up and proxying according to what I defined here.  But I don't see any logs about it actually attempting to proxy anything (either in that pod, or my ingress-controller pod).

Am I doing something wrong for it to be returning a 502?

Answer (score 3):

As per documentation [here](https://github.com/stakater/ProxyInjector#usage), 
`authproxy.stakater.com/listen` is what proxy listens on. so it should be either `0.0.0.0:80` or `0.0.0.0:443`. So every call redirected by nginx to the service lands on the proxy container. After the request is verified by keycloak. it will redirect it to the url mentioned in `authproxy.stakater.com/redirection-url` e.g. https://cool.myweb.app.com (should be accessible to keycloak). The redirected request from keycloak will land again on the proxy container but this time is authenticated and will be redirected to `authproxy.stakater.com/upstream-url` i.e. your app you are trying to proxy e.g.

```
Recommended setting is to run proxy on port 80/443 and app on any other port e.g. 3000 etc.
```

See [Flow diagram](https://github.com/stakater/ProxyInjector/blob/master/docs/ProxyInjectorFlow.md) for further reference.

Feel free to open an issue in the repository, if you have any further questions.
or ask in the [Stakater slack channel](https://stakater.slack.com/messages/CFCP3MUR4/)